# Print value of number (int) spelled out

Tags: c#

is there an out-of-box way to spell out an int in C#? For example if I have:

```
int a = 53;
```

I want to print:

```
"fifty three"
```

not

```
"53"
```

If not, does anybody have any examples on how to accomplis this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to write that code yourself.  If had to guess, I'd say it's not in the framework because it'd be near impossible to localize (there's much more to this than just the names of digits: word order, hyphen rules, etc).

This brings back memories because it was an assignment from my very first programming course back in college, so it shouldn't be too hard for you to write one just in English.

Comment: Localization would be a pain -- I'm just thinking about the hassles of French "98" "Quatre-Vingt dixhuit" (Literally four-twenty eighteen)

Comment: Localization is often a pain but this really should be out-of-the-box with some minor customisations like hyphens.

Answer (score 8):

> Here is code for converting number to
>   words.
>
> ```
> using System;
> namespace WpfApplication1
> {
>  public class NumberToEnglish
>   {
>    public String changeNumericToWords(double numb)
>    {
>     String num = numb.ToString();
>     return changeToWords(num, false);
>    }
>    public String changeCurrencyToWords(String numb)
>    {
>     return changeToWords(numb, true);
>    }
>    public String changeNumericToWords(String numb)
>    {
>     return changeToWords(numb, false);
>    }
>    public String changeCurrencyToWords(double numb)
>    {
>     return changeToWords(numb.ToString(), true);
>    }
>    private String changeToWords(String numb, bool isCurrency)
>    {
>    String val = "", wholeNo = numb, points = "", andStr = "", pointStr="";
>    String endStr = (isCurrency) ? ("Only") : ("");
>    try
>    {
>     int decimalPlace = numb.IndexOf(".");
>     if (decimalPlace > 0)
>     {
>      wholeNo = numb.Substring(0, decimalPlace);
>      points = numb.Substring(decimalPlace+1);
>      if (Convert.ToInt32(points) > 0)
>      {
>       andStr = (isCurrency)?("and"):("point");// just to separate whole numbers from > points/cents
>       endStr = (isCurrency) ? ("Cents "+endStr) : ("");
>       pointStr = translateCents(points);
>      }
>     }
>     val = String.Format("{0} {1}{2} {3}",translateWholeNumber(wholeNo).Trim(),andStr,pointStr,endStr);
>    }
>    catch { ;}
>    return val;
>   }
>    private String translateWholeNumber(String number)
>    {
>     string word = "";
>     try
>     {
>      bool beginsZero = false;//tests for 0XX
>      bool isDone = false;//test if already translated
>      double dblAmt = (Convert.ToDouble(number));
>      //if ((dblAmt > 0) && number.StartsWith("0"))
>      if (dblAmt > 0)
>      {//test for zero or digit zero in a nuemric
>       beginsZero = number.StartsWith("0");
>
>       int numDigits = number.Length;
>       int pos = 0;//store digit grouping
>       String place = "";//digit grouping name:hundres,thousand,etc...
>       switch (numDigits)
>       {
>        case 1://ones' range
>         word = ones(number);
>         isDone = true;
>         break;
>        case 2://tens' range
>         word = tens(number);
>         isDone = true;
>         break;
>        case 3://hundreds' range
>         pos = (numDigits % 3) + 1;
>         place = " Hundred ";
>         break;
>        case 4://thousands' range
>        case 5:
>        case 6:
>         pos = (numDigits % 4) + 1;
>         place = " Thousand ";
>         break;
>        case 7://millions' range
>        case 8:
>        case 9:
>         pos = (numDigits % 7) + 1;
>         place = " Million ";
>         break;
>        case 10://Billions's range
>         pos = (numDigits % 10) + 1;
>         place = " Billion ";
>         break;
>        //add extra case options for anything above Billion...
>        default:
>         isDone = true;
>         break;
>       }
>       if (!isDone)
>       {//if transalation is not done, continue...(Recursion comes in now!!)
>        word = translateWholeNumber(number.Substring(0, pos)) + place + translateWholeNumber(number.Substring(pos));
>        //check for trailing zeros
>        if (beginsZero) word = " and " + word.Trim();
>       }
>       //ignore digit grouping names
>       if (word.Trim().Equals(place.Trim())) word = "";
>      }
>     }
>     catch { ;}
>     return word.Trim();
>    }
>    private String tens(String digit)
>    {
>     int digt = Convert.ToInt32(digit);
>     String name = null;
>     switch (digt)
>     {
>      case 10:
>       name = "Ten";
>       break;
>      case 11:
>       name = "Eleven";
>       break;
>      case 12:
>       name = "Twelve";
>       break;
>      case 13:
>       name = "Thirteen";
>       break;
>      case 14:
>       name = "Fourteen";
>       break;
>      case 15:
>       name = "Fifteen";
>       break;
>      case 16:
>       name = "Sixteen";
>       break;
>      case 17:
>       name = "Seventeen";
>       break;
>      case 18:
>       name = "Eighteen";
>       break;
>      case 19:
>       name = "Nineteen";
>       break;
>      case 20:
>       name = "Twenty";
>       break;
>      case 30:
>       name = "Thirty";
>       break;
>      case 40:
>       name = "Fourty";
>       break;
>      case 50:
>       name = "Fifty";
>       break;
>      case 60:
>       name = "Sixty";
>       break;
>      case 70:
>       name = "Seventy";
>       break;
>      case 80:
>       name = "Eighty";
>       break;
>      case 90:
>       name = "Ninety";
>       break;
>      default:
>       if (digt > 0)
>       {
>        name = tens(digit.Substring(0, 1) + "0") + "" + ones(digit.Substring(1));
>       }
>       break;
>     }
>     return name;
>    }
>    private String ones(String digit)
>    {
>     int digt = Convert.ToInt32(digit);
>     String name = "";
>     switch (digt)
>     {
>      case 1:
>       name = "One";
>       break;
>      case 2:
>       name = "Two";
>       break;
>      case 3:
>       name = "Three";
>       break;
>      case 4:
>       name = "Four";
>       break;
>      case 5:
>       name = "Five";
>       break;
>      case 6:
>       name = "Six";
>       break;
>      case 7:
>       name = "Seven";
>       break;
>      case 8:
>       name = "Eight";
>       break;
>      case 9:
>       name = "Nine";
>       break;
>     }
>     return name;
>    }
>    private String translateCents(String cents)
>    {
>     String cts = "", digit = "", engOne = "";
>      for (int i = 0; i < cents.Length; i++)
>      {
>       digit = cents[i].ToString();
>       if (digit.Equals("0"))
>       {
>        engOne = "Zero";
>       }
>       else
>       {
>        engOne = ones(digit);
>       }
>       cts += " " + engOne;
>      }
>     return cts;
>    }
>   }
>  }
> ```
>
> create a class file in your project,
>   copy this code to your class file.
>   Change the namespace to your project
>   namespace.
>
> create obj of that class something
>   like this
>
> ```
> NumberToEnglish objnumber = new NumberToEnglish();
> ```
>
> and with
>   `objnumber.changeNumericToWords(100);`
>
> with that function you will get number
>   into word.

source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/42b5bb54-dfd6-4c5b-8d51-82e5fc29f8e8
author: Hiran Repakula

He uses instance method, but you can make these methods `static`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an additional way, just for kicks.

```
public static class NumericSpelling
{
    private const long Quadrillion = Trillion * 1000;
    private const long Trillion = Billion * 1000;
    private const long Billion = Million * 1000;
    private const long Million = Thousand * 1000;
    private const long Thousand = Hundred * 10;
    private const long Hundred = 100;

    public static string ToVerbal(this int value) { return ToVerbal((long)value); }

    public static string ToVerbal(this long value)
    {
        if (value == 0) return "zero";

        if (value < 0)
        {
            return "negative " + ToVerbal(Math.Abs(value));
        }

        System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        int unit = 0;

        if (value >= Quadrillion)
        {
            unit = (int)(value / Quadrillion);
            value -= unit * Quadrillion;

            builder.AppendFormat("{0}{1} quadrillion", builder.Length > 0 ? ", " : string.Empty, ToVerbal(unit));
        }

        if (value >= Trillion)
        {
            unit = (int)(value / Trillion);
            value -= unit * Trillion;

            builder.AppendFormat("{0}{1} trillion", builder.Length > 0 ? ", " : string.Empty, ToVerbal(unit));
        }

        if (value >= Billion)
        {
            unit = (int)(value / Billion);
            value -= unit * Billion;

            builder.AppendFormat("{0}{1} billion", builder.Length > 0 ? ", " : string.Empty, ToVerbal(unit));
        }

        if (value >= Million)
        {
            unit = (int)(value / Million);
            value -= unit * Million;

            builder.AppendFormat("{0}{1} million", builder.Length > 0 ? ", " : string.Empty, ToVerbal(unit));
        }

        if (value >= Thousand)
        {
            unit = (int)(value / Thousand);
            value -= unit * Thousand;

            builder.AppendFormat("{0}{1} thousand", builder.Length > 0 ? ", " : string.Empty, ToVerbal(unit));
        }

        if (value >= Hundred)
        {
            unit = (int)(value / Hundred);
            value -= unit * Hundred;

            builder.AppendFormat("{0}{1} hundred", builder.Length > 0 ? ", " : string.Empty, ToVerbal(unit));
        }

        if (builder.Length > 0 && value > 0) builder.AppendFormat(" and");

        if (value >= 90)
        {
            value -= 90;

            builder.AppendFormat("{0}ninety", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        }

        if (value >= 80)
        {
            value -= 80;

            builder.AppendFormat("{0}eighty", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        }

        if (value >= 70)
        {
            value -= 70;

            builder.AppendFormat("{0}seventy", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        }

        if (value >= 60)
        {
            value -= 60;

            builder.AppendFormat("{0}sixty", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        }

        if (value >= 50)
        {
            value -= 50;

            builder.AppendFormat("{0}fifty", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        }

        if (value >= 40)
        {
            value -= 40;

            builder.AppendFormat("{0}forty", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        }

        if (value >= 30)
        {
            value -= 30;

            builder.AppendFormat("{0}thirty", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        }

        if (value >= 20)
        {
            value -= 20;

            builder.AppendFormat("{0}twenty", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        }

        if (value == 19) builder.AppendFormat("{0}nineteen", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        if (value == 18) builder.AppendFormat("{0}eighteen", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        if (value == 17) builder.AppendFormat("{0}seventeen", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        if (value == 16) builder.AppendFormat("{0}sixteen", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        if (value == 15) builder.AppendFormat("{0}fifteen", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        if (value == 14) builder.AppendFormat("{0}fourteen", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        if (value == 13) builder.AppendFormat("{0}thirteen", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        if (value == 12) builder.AppendFormat("{0}twelve", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        if (value == 11) builder.AppendFormat("{0}eleven", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        if (value == 10) builder.AppendFormat("{0}ten", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        if (value == 9) builder.AppendFormat("{0}nine", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        if (value == 8) builder.AppendFormat("{0}eight", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        if (value == 7) builder.AppendFormat("{0}seven", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        if (value == 6) builder.AppendFormat("{0}six", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        if (value == 5) builder.AppendFormat("{0}five", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        if (value == 4) builder.AppendFormat("{0}four", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        if (value == 3) builder.AppendFormat("{0}three", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        if (value == 2) builder.AppendFormat("{0}two", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);
        if (value == 1) builder.AppendFormat("{0}one", builder.Length > 0 ? " " : string.Empty);

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Input:

```
int first = 10447;
long second = 10576749323475;
int third = 0;
int fourth = -1095;
int fifth = 100;
int sixth = 102;
int seventh = 10004;
int eight = 100025;

Console.WriteLine(first.ToVerbal());
Console.WriteLine(second.ToVerbal());
Console.WriteLine(third.ToVerbal());
Console.WriteLine(fourth.ToVerbal());
Console.WriteLine(fifth.ToVerbal());
Console.WriteLine(sixth.ToVerbal());
Console.WriteLine(seventh.ToVerbal());
Console.WriteLine(eight.ToVerbal());
```

Output:

```
ten thousand, four hundred and forty seven
ten trillion, five hundred and seventy six billion, seven hundred and forty nine million, three hundred and twenty three thousand, four hundred and seventy five
zero
negative one thousand and ninety five
one hundred
one hundred and two
ten thousand and four
one hundred thousand and twenty five
```

Comment: Could you please let me know how can this be achieved adopting OOP concepts, cleaner code and TDD as well.

Answer (score 4):

If all else fails, ask Bill Gates and his crew. This should get you started

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=213360

Answer (score 3):

The [article here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/NumberToWords.aspx) gives a solution to converting an integer to words.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do this. The [International Components for Unicode](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/) project has a RuleBasedNumberFormatter with a "spell out" option. It even supports full localization.

The only snag is that it is only available in C, C++, and Java. There is an initiative going in the [icu.net](https://github.com/sillsdev/icu-dotnet) project (for both .NET Framework and .NET Standard 1.6), but this feature and many others are still not ported yet. However, a contribution could solve that quite nicely.

There is also [a tool](http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icuapps/trunk/CSharp/genicuwrapper/) that is supposed to be able to automatically generate a C# wrapper library around the ICU4C library, but I haven't tried it.

[Other options](http://site.icu-project.org/related) are available for other programming languages.