# Using C# Identify numeric values in a string and convert to pronousing string

Tags: c#, regex

Given the following input text:

> John was born in the year **1965**, he joined his first job on **10/22/89**,
>   his first salary was **$2500**. Today he makes **USD 10,000** per month. He
>   started his own company on **08/2013**

C# function should recognize all numeric words (for known patterns) and convert (replace) those in to words the we we pronounce it.

**Using above example**

- 1965 : Nineteen sixty five
- 10/22/89 : October twenty second Nineteen eight nine
- $2500 : Two thousands
- USD 10,000 : Ten thousands
- 08/2013 : August twenty thirteen

There could be more combinations of this like

- 2015-09-02
- $2500
- $ 2500
- $ 2,500

Going through some research here are some options for numbers:

Number to words using [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#number-to-words), it can change numbers to words using the `ToWords` extension:

- 1.ToWords() => "one"
- 10.ToWords() => "ten"
- 11.ToWords() => "eleven"
- 122.ToWords() => "one hundred and twenty-two"
- 3501.ToWords() => "three thousand five hundred and one"

Also, nice solution from [Adam Robinson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2601001/942855) as well for Number to String

Couldn't find a better/existing solution for converting dates to pronouncing string.

**For who get confused about recognizing the numbers & dates, I will use Regex to identify those, my question is to converting the identified date, numbers to human pronouncing words**

---

Approach here is to

- step 1) using a regex find all currency and numbers
- step 2) using [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#number-to-words) convert numbers/currency to words
- step 3) using a regex find all dates
- step 4) **write a function or find a plugin, that can convert any date format to human pronouncing words**.

At this point, I am stuck with step 4.

Comment: A possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600746/print-value-of-number-int-spelled-out.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks that covers currency conversion, need to come up with similar code for dates as well.

Comment: You should understand it is not a trivial regex to detect all possible date time formats. Right now, your question is too broad to answer. The only thing I can suggest now is that you need to use some entity detector to parse the text and get the numbers, currencies, dates, and then parse each with dedicated algorithm.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew At this time, I have few known formats to recognize, date, currency and regular number, my challenge is not to identify the numeric type, I can achieve this with some RegEx, my challenge it to convert the dates to human pronouncing string example, 10/1983 should be October Nineteen eighty three

Comment: This is impossible unless you can find a way to determine whether `1965` is a year ("nineteen sixty five") or not ("nineteen hundred sixty five").

Comment: @hvd for now business would like to go with a assumption if there is a 4 digit number with spaces before and after, verify that is a valid year and then consider it as Year and convert it to words

Comment: @hvd BTW did you just down vote the question? If you did, I pity you kid..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer). It can convert, among other things, dates and values to their corresponding words.

Comment: I was just looking at it. Humanizer is doing good for number but not for dates

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> numericValues = new List<String>();
String tempValue = String.Empty;

for(int i =0; i < sourceString.length;i++)
{
   if(Char.IsDigit(sourcestring[i]) || sourcestring[i] == '/' || sourcestring[i] == '$')//Etc.. special characters
   {
     tempValue = tempValue  + sourcestring[i]
   }
   else
   {
      if(tempValue != String.Empty)
      {
         numericValues.Add(tempValue);
         tempValue = String.Empty
      }
   }
}
```

This does not cover cases like "USD 10,000" and doesn't handle spaces but it should give you a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Number to words using [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#number-to-words), it can change numbers to words using the `ToWords` extension:

- 1.ToWords() => "one"
- 10.ToWords() => "ten"
- 11.ToWords() => "eleven"
- 122.ToWords() => "one hundred and twenty-two"
- 3501.ToWords() => "three thousand five hundred and one"

Code [example](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer/blob/dev/src/Humanizer/Localisation/NumberToWords/EnglishNumberToWordsConverter.cs)

Also, nice solution from [Adam Robinson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2601001/942855) as well for Number to String

Couldn't find a better/existing solution for dates to pronouncing string.